# PHP class recursion: can I create an object of given class inside a method of own class?

Tags: php, class, recursion

Here's what I'd like to do :

```
class number {
  var $value ;
  function number($n=0) {
    $this->value = $n ;
  }
  function add($n) {
    $x = new number($n) ;
    $this->value += $x->value ;
  }
}
```

This example is of course ridiculous, but it illustrates the kind of recursion I'd like to do in a more serious project. (I'll be in fact manipulating images instead of numbers, but I don't suppose it matters here.)

So, should it work ?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself and see, it would have been quicker than posting here and waiting for an answer.... though please start using PHP5 tutorials rather than PHP4 tutorials

Answer (score 1):

```
class Number {

    protected $value;

    public function __construct($n = 0) {
        $this->value = $n;
    }

    public function add($n) {
        $x = new static($n);  // or self($x), if you're on PHP < 5.3
        $this->value += $x->value;
    }

}
```

Fixed it to actually make it work. Yes, this is entirely possible and sensible (well, it's debatable whether *this particular* code makes sense, but in general). This is not really recursion. You're just instantiating a class inside a method of another class. It doesn't matter in the slightest that the class you're instantiating is the same as the class that the method you're instantiating it in belongs to (now that's a complicated sentence).

Comment: Thank you. It seems the main difference between your code and mine is that yours is in PHP5 and mine in PHP4. Am I right ?

Comment: And that `$x->value` is not a method call.

Answer (score 0):

Made example for you. Here is small example:

```
  class number {
      var $value ;
      function number($n=0) {
      $this->value = $n ;
  }
  function add($n) {
      $x = new number($n) ;
      $this->value += $x->value ;
      return $this->value;
  }
}

$foo = new number;
echo $foo->add(2);
echo $foo->add(2);
```

There was error in your code "$x->value()". Value is not method - it field and should call $x->value